# Is there a way to click in headless chrome?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to click on the "my network" button in Linkedin profile. I can use the 'goto' method to go to that url directly but I want to be able to click it.

I have tried to use the 'copy selector' but it does not seem to work.

```
const BUTTON_SELECTOR = '#mynetwork-nav-item';
    await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);
```

I am able to login but it does not work after that.

Complete code-

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  /* Initiate the Puppeteer browser */
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: { width: 1366, height: 768 }});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(`https://www.linkedin.com`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

  let element, formElement, tabs;
  element = await page.$x(`//a[contains(text(),'Sign in')]`);
    await element[0].click();
    await page.waitForNavigation();

    element = await page.$x(`//*[@id="username"]`);
    await element[0].type(`some_id@example.com`);

    element = await page.$x(`(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Welcome Back'])[1]/following::div[3]`);
    await element[0].click();

    element = await page.$x(`//*[@id="password"]`);
    await element[0].click();

    element = await page.$x(`//*[@id="password"]`);
    await element[0].type(`some_password`);

    await page.keyboard.press(`Enter`)

    const MY_NETWORK_BUTTON = '#mynetwork-tab-icon';
    await page.waitForSelector(MY_NETWORK_BUTTON, {visible: true});
    const [response] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(), // The promise resolves after navigation has finished
    page.click(MY_NETWORK_BUTTON), // Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
    ]);

    console.log('CURRENT URL IS: ', response.url());
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly try to wait for the selector, then you should change the selector and after that click on it.

**UPDATED:**

```
const MY_NETWORK_BUTTON = '#mynetwork-tab-icon';
await page.waitForSelector(MY_NETWORK_BUTTON, {visible: true});
const [response] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(), // The promise resolves after navigation has finished
  page.click(MY_NETWORK_BUTTON), // Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
]);

console.log('CURRENT URL IS: ', response.url());
```

**OUTPUT:**

> CURRENT URL IS:  https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/

Comment: Did you test this on the page? Because it does not seem to work for me.

Comment: yep, it works, just checked it with your edited code and still works.

Comment: You can check that url is changed and you are on my network page. I have updated the answer with `console.log`. Check it please, and tell me what does it say

Comment: Error message: (node:30434) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null
    at /home/kaustubh/imdb.js:35:43
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:30434) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.

Answer (score 0):

Simply waiting for navigation to finish should be enough to change tabs properly

```
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click(MY_NETWORK_BUTTON)
]);
```

However the issue may be in something else, for instance when i initially created account the webpage prompted me to add my phone number right after logging in, so perhaps you cannot click the network tab, because this selector is not present for some other reason.

It is usually ill advised to login using the form, as a lot of webpages have counter measures against **scraping**/non human user. Linkedin in particular can ask you to complete the captcha to prove you are not a robot after logging in.

If you really want to login in this way you can improve your code responsible by changing those selectors into simple

```
await page.goto("https:\/\/www.linkedin.com", { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

await page.type("input[name='session_key']",email);
await page.type("input[name='session_password']",password);
await page.keyboard.press(`Enter`);
```

otherwise i would suggest using a cookie to log in, which would even more simplify the code.

You can get the list of cookies in a format accepted by puppeteer by calling

```
await page.cookies();
```

And later set them with

```
await page.setCookie(cookie)
```

I am not exactly sure of the format linkedin uses to store user information inside of the cookies, but it seems that loading just the cookie named `li_at` is enough e.g.

```
await page.setCookie({
    "name": "li_at",
    "value": INSERT VALUE HERE,
    "domain": ".www.linkedin.com",
    "path": "/",
    "size": 157,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "secure": true,
    "session": false
})
```

Comment: I have seen the response of the process in 'headless: false' mode, there are no popups in that page. I am getting the following error - 
(node:31195) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at /home/kaustubh/imdb.js:35:34
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:31195) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: this error has nothing to do with the described issue, it seems that somehwere in your code ( ` /home/kaustubh/imdb.js:35:34` ) you are referencing non existent response object.

Comment: imdb.js is the name of the this file. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: i do realize it's most likely a name of that file, however it seems that not all code was provided by you (the part causing the issue in particular)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the code. Please take a look.

Comment: Is it necessary to even log the url of the response? 

according to puppeteer documentation `page.waitForNavigation()` returns: `<Promise<?Response>>` Promise which resolves to the main resource response. In case of multiple redirects, the navigation will resolve with the response of the last redirect. In case of navigation to a different anchor or navigation due to History API usage, the navigation will resolve with null.
So i would assume that for one of the reasons it resolves null